# Navigation Component: How to clear back stack WHEN NAVIGATING FROM FRAGMENT TO ACTIVITY?

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, android-navigation

Please make sure to read the full question before marking it as repeated.

I am well aware of **popUpto**, **popUpToInclusive** and **launchSingleTop** attributes on navigation xml. They simply do **NOT** apply when navigating from a **FRAGMENT** to a **ACTIVITY** (even though they still appear in the navigation xml). I have tried dozens of different solutions and I am searching for an answer to this for the past 3 days!

To let you guys know, this is the **ONLY** solution so far that actually works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59795636/6952763

But the solution itself is so ugly that I am not willing to implement it myself. Relaunching the same activity and accepting the flashing black screen when doing it for me just doesn't seem like an option.

The closest I have got from a good working solution was https://stackoverflow.com/a/63566415/6952763 which is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/63169732/6952763 but for some reason when adding the combination of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` together with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` results on the target Activity to be created/destroyed/recreated multiple times (around 8 times). It's easy to achieve it when navigating between Fragments. Just the xml parameters that I mentioned above already do the work. The ask here is from **FRAGMENT** to **ACTIVITY** which is giving me headaches :D

Summarising the question: I want to completely clear the backstack when going from **FRAGMENT_Login** (example) to **ACTIVITY_home** using **Navigation Component**. Any idea how to achieve this?

So far, my code is something around this:

**FRAGMENT ORIGIN**

```
   private fun proceedToHome(user: UserEntity?){
        if(user != null && user.id != 0L){
            val direction = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginToMainHostActivity(user.id)
            val extras = ActivityNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                .build()
            val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
                .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
                .build()
            findNavController().navigate(direction.actionId, direction.arguments, navOptions, extras)
        }
    }
```

**ACTIVITY DESTINATION:**

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val mBinding = ActivityMainHostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mBinding.root)
        
        navController = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.activity_main_host_content) as NavHostFragment).navController
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.main_host_navigation, intent.extras)

        mBinding.activityMainHostNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

The code above causes the Activity to be created/destroyed/recreated multiple times and based on my tests I think it's the combination of those 2 Intent flags I am using. If I use only `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` or only `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` then I don't get the issue but also don't clear the backstack so when user presses back button on the activity he is brought back to the **fragment**.

I could just call `requireActivity().finish()` on the origin fragment but that also seems like a hack. I feel like all I am missing is some sort of detail about the use of those flags...

Any help will be deeply appreciated! <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working. The above example is working just as it should, the only catch is **REMOVE** the **POPUPTO**, **POPUPTOINCLUSIVE** and **LAUNCHSINGLETOP** attributes from the **ACTION** related to this Fragment-Activity transition **EVEN IF THESE ATTRIBUTES HAVE VALUE "FALSE"**. If you just toggle them off using the design of navigation xml they will still be present and toggled as false. **REMOVE THEM**.

Thanks all.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Do you have an idea how to preserve login activity on stack but remove all fragment backstack in LoginActivity? i.e. when you return to LoginActivity it should start from home destination of LoginActivity again.